# Position After JQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 div on my page, 2 little div on the center of the page and 2 big div outside the page. When i clicked the left little div, the whole page move left and pull the big div from the left. Same with the right little div. Because i have some hover effect on my little divs, after i pull the big div outside the window, the hover effect will act again.
Do i need to set their CSS after the animation finish to make sure the little div has moved out of the window?

here is the code

```
<div id="little_left">
        <div id="upper">
        <img src="" alt="imge"/>
        <p>left</p>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="big_left">

    </div>
    <div id="little_right">
        <div id="upper">
        <img src="" alt="right"/>
        <p>right</p>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="big_right">

    </div>
```

Then the JS code ( now with the hover effect )

```
    $("#little_left").animate({"left":"0"},1000,function(e){
            $(this).hover(function(e){
                    $(this).css("z-index",$("#little_right").css("z-index")+1);
                    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({"top":"50",
                                     "left":"250",
                                     "width":"500",
                                     "height":"500",
                                     "border-radius":"15"
                                     },500);
                },function(e){

                    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({"top":"20",
                                     "left":"0",
                                     "width":DivWidth,
                                     "height":DivHeight,
                                     "border-radius":"0"
                                     },250,function(e){
                                         $(this).css("z-index",$("#little_right").css("z-index")-1);});

                });
    });
$("#little_right").animate({"right":"0"},1000,function(e){
    $(this).hover(function(e){
            $(this).css("z-index",$("#little_left").css("z-index")+1);
                    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({"top":"50",
                                     "right":"250",
                                     "width":"500",
                                     "height":"500",
                                     "border-radius":"15",
                                      },500);
                },function(e){

                    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({"top":"20",
                                     "right":"0",
                                     "width":DivWidth,
                                     "height":DivHeight,
                                     "border-radius":"0"
                                     },250,function(e){
                                         $(this).css("z-index",$("#little_left").css("z-index")-1);});

                });
});

$("#little_left").click(function(e) {
    $(this).animate({"left":-DivWidth},500);
    $("#little_right").animate({"left":-winWidth},1000);
    $("#big_left").animate({"left":"0"},1000);

});
$("#little_right").click(function(e) {
    $(this).animate({"right":-DivWidth},500);
    $("#little_left").animate({"left":winWidth},1000);
    $("#big_right").animate({"left":"0"},1000);
});
```

CSS   the 2 big div are outside the window ,  only 2 little divs are shown inside the window

Comment: having JSFiddle would make solving this much faster :D

Comment: Is there any way i can stop the hover function during my animation?

Comment: @user3265085 post a fiddle or your complete code

Comment: @user3265085 try `promise()`. *Know more* : ***https://api.jquery.com/promise/***

Comment: You mean you want to remove the hover effect once the animation is done, or only during the animation? 

$('#little_right').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');